# How can I implement "firewall rules" style timebased ACL implemantation ? (C#, Sql Server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, acl, servicestack, rule

I'm using ServiceStack and I dont know if my way is true or not for this requirement with ServiceStack Permission support.

Now rule table structure is:

- TargetRole
- TargetUserId
- DENY/ALLOW
- ActionTypeEnum
- StartDate
- EndDate
- StartHour
- EndHour
- RunningEnum ([Flags] OnlyOnce=1,Monday=2,....,Sunday=128)

Rule:
All admins could not (DENY) crateUser (ACTIONTYPEENUM.CREATEUSER) every Mondays (RUNNINGENUM=2) between 12-17 hours (STARTHOUR=12,ENDHOUR=17)

So I have to solve these rules (and if I can I have to bind with ServiceStack Permission), Is there any problem on my way or any better framework or ruleresolver in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no framework for ACL implemantation in C#. You have to write your own! So do I :)

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack's [RequireRole and RequiredPermissions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) attributes let you mark what Roles / Permission a service needs. The [implementation of RequireRole](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequiredRoleAttribute.cs#L32) just calls [IAuthSession.HasRole()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/IAuthSession.cs#L26) (or IAuthSession.HasPermission()) which determines whether the user has the role specified.

When you register your own [CustomUserSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/AppHost.cs#L171) you can implement the above methods to do exactly what you need.

The alternative is to ignore the existing Roles/Permissions support and just create your own [Request Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) and have it execute before each request you want validated.